# When did phasers replace cannons in Star Trek ships?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, star-trek-enterprise

Enterprise NX-01 uses phase and plasma cannons as well as torpedoes. NCC-1031 also used cannons throughout the series, until *Such Sweet Sorrow* part II. In fact at the Battle of the Binary Stars, both [Federation and Klingon fleets were using cannons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKeZ4eqYQ5I).

[image: Battle of the Binary Stars]

While Memory-Alpha states the Discovery has phaser banks they never seem to be used.

However in *Such Sweet Sorrow part II* NCC-1701 was clearly using her phasers (photo):

[image: Enterprise aft phasers]

When did Starfleet begin using phaser banks as a primary weapon?

Comment: AFAIK NCC-1031 never used cannons. It's always had phaser banks. http://fsd.trekships.org/enterprise/1701/1701-wds-1.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The NX class had plasma cannons as it's primary armament, when their arsenal proved inadequate, they upgraded the armament to the new "Phase cannons" and by the 23rd century phasers were invented. Phaser rifles were introduced at sometime before 2265, Phasers onboard starships sometime in the he 23rd century.